# Read-only JMS topic subscription? (or preserve JMS messages when dequeuing)

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have an backlogged topic of ActiveMQ messages for customer data in a production environment, and I need to write a script that dequeues it and does whatever business logic is necessary.

If something goes wrong in the business logic, but I've already read the message (via JMS probably), that would presumably mean all the messages are gone - and I'd be in huge trouble.

Is there a way to read the messages without deleting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pattern in messaging.  If you're using the JMS API you have a couple of options:

1. Use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode when you create your session and acknowledge the message once the business logic is complete.  If the business logic fails don't acknowledge the message and it won't be removed from the queue.
2. Use a transacted session. If the business logic completes successfully then commit the transaction. If the business fails then rollback the transaction.

Both of these are very common and you can find more information about all the proper API calls, etc. using your favorite search engine.